# Macro for upper & lowercase

Tags: microsoft-excel

On my Excel spreadsheet I have cells with words and some cells are all uppercase, some are all lowercase and some are a mixture.  Is there a way to get all cells to display the first letter as uppercase and the other letters as lowercase?

Comment: Do you only want to change the _display_ of the words, or do you want to actually change the _value_?

Comment: I agree with Adam, this sounds like a formatting question rather than a calculation question.  But best to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` to get *all* text except the first letter lower case:

`=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))&LOWER(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-1))`